# Convert string array to datetime and compare

Tags: python

I just started programming with Python, and have some simple questions (probably). What I would like to do is compare some timestamps to find the closest that isn't later then now.

Basically what Iam trying to do is getting the current track played on the radio, and they have a feed that show the next 20 or so with time for when the track starts. I want to get whats playing right now!

Here is an example array of strings:

```
examples = ['2012-12-10 02:06:45', '2012-12-10 02:02:43', '2012-12-10 01:58:53']
```

Now what I would like to do is compare the time closest to now (but not later) to see whats currently playing.

This is my script so far:

```
import datetime, itertools, time
currentTimeMachine = datetime.datetime.now()
now = currentTimeMachine.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

examples = ['2012-12-10 02:06:45', '2012-12-10 02:02:43', '2012-12-10 01:58:53']
tmsg = examples.strftime('%d%b%Y')


 print [x for x in itertools.takewhile( lambda t: now > datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), examples )][-1]
```

The last bit there I picked up somwhere else, but I cant seem to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you want to convert to datetime objects and compare the resulting objects, not convert to string and compare the strings.

Comment: `tmsg = examples.strftime('%d%b%Y')` is not valid. Is it your problem?

Comment: I guess so. Atleast a big part of it. I've been having a lot of problems with the datetime and strftime functions. They don't seem to work like their described in the documentation.

Comment: The first part of the problem is that you've mixed up `strftime` and `strptime`. The second is that you can't call a function on a `list` and expect it to be applied to all members of that list—the way to do that is a list comprehension (`[strptime(example, '%d%b%Y') for example in examples]`) or the `map` function. The third is that your `takewhile` predicate tries to compare each `datetime`s with a string instead of a `datetime`; just use `now = datetime.datetime.now()` as the thing to compare to.

Comment: … and the big problem is that you "picked up" some code that doesn't actually do what you want, and didn't think through what it does. Even if you get it right, that will not give you the latest timestamp before the present, it'll give you the timestamp right before the first one in the future (which is only the same thing if you keep the `examples` sorted in ascending date order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers have fixed your errors, so your algorithm now runs properly.

But the algorithm itself is wrong. You want to get the closest to the present without going over. But what you've written is:

```
 [x for x in itertools.takewhile(pred, examples)][-1]
```

Think about what this means. First, `takewhile` will return examples until one of them fails the predicate. Then you're taking the last one that succeeded. So, if your examples looked like this:

```
[now-3, now-10, now-5, now+3, now-9, now-1, now+9]
```

First, `takewhile` will yield `now-3, now-10, now-5` and then stop because `pred(now+3)` returns False. Then, you take the last one, `now-5`.

This *would* work if you sorted the examples in ascending order:

```
[now-10, now-9, now-5, now-3, now-1, now+3, now+9]
```

Now `takewhile` will yield everything up to `now-1`, so the last thing it yields is the one you want.

But the example in your initial question were in *descending* order, and in the comment to Anthony Kong's answer, you added some more that aren't in any order at all. So, you obviously can't rely on them being in sorted order. So, one possible fix is to sort them:

```
>>> import datetime, itertools, time
>>> currentTimeMachine = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print [x for x in itertools.takewhile(lambda t: currentTimeMachine  > datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), sorted(examples))][-1]
2012-12-10 02:06:45
```

Or, to make things a bit more readable, break up that last line, and get rid of the extraneous list comprehension:

```
>>> exampleDates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for t in examples]
>>> def beforeNow(t):
...     return currentTimeMachine > t
>>> print list(itertools.takewhile(beforeNow, sorted(exampleDates))[-1]
```

However, this is kind of a silly way to do things. What you really want is the maximum value in examples that isn't after the present. So just translate that English sentence into code:

```
>>> print max(x for x in exampleDates if x <= currentTimeMachine)
```

Let's put it all together:

```
>>> examples = ['2012-12-10 02:06:45', '2012-12-10 02:02:43', '2012-12-10 01:58:53']
>>> exampleDates = (datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for t in examples)
>>> currentTimeMachine = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print max(t for t in exampleDates if t <= currentTimeMachine)
2012-12-10 02:06:45
```

I used a generator expression rather than a list for `exampleDates` because you don't actually need the list for anything you just need to iterate over it once. If you want to keep it around for inspection or repeated use, change the parens to square brackets.

Also, I changed the `<` to `<=`, because you said "isn't later then now" rather than "is earlier than now" (in other words, now should count).

As a side note, because you happen to have ISO-esque timestamps, you actually *can* sort them as strings:

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> currentTimeMachine = datetime.datetime.strftime(now, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> print max(t for t in examples if t <= currentTimeMachine)
2012-12-10 02:06:45
```

There's no good reason to do things this way, and it will invariably lead you to bugs when you get timestamps in slightly different formats (e.g., `'2012-12-10 02:06:45'` compares before `'2012-12-10Z01:06:45'`), but it isn't actually a problem with your original code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for beeing so detailed. It worked excellent. The statement that compares the time makes a lot of sense to me. I see what you did there! Again, thanks for telling me what actually is going on, and why you do the things you do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` to convert a string to a datetime object.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> examples = ['2012-12-10 02:06:45', '2012-12-10 02:02:43', '2012-12-10 01:58:53']
>>> parsed_datetimes = [datetime.datetime.strptime(e, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for e in examples]
>>> parsed_datetimes
[datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 10, 2, 6, 45), datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 10, 2, 2, 43), datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 10, 1, 58, 53)]
```

This will then get the minimum difference datetime, "*closest to now*", from the current datetime `now`:

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> min_time_diff, min_datetime = min((now - i, i) for i in parsed_datetimes)
>>> min_time_diff, min_datetime
(datetime.timedelta(0, 36265, 626000), datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 10, 2, 6, 45))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not post the error message, so based on the code your post, there are a few issues

1) `tmsg = examples.strftime('%d%b%Y')` won't work because you apply a call on strftime the list

2) As others have pointed out already, in the takewhile you're comparing string with datetime.

This will work:

```
>>> import datetime, itertools, time
>>> currentTimeMachine = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print [x for x in itertools.takewhile( lambda t: currentTimeMachine  > datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), examples )][-1]
2012-12-10 01:58:53
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your fast reply. However, I've added some newer timestamps, and it seems to be taking the lowest one, no matter what. Example: The time is 03:08 now (for me), and I've added a few newer stamps: 
   examples = ['2012-12-10 03:00:10', '2012-12-10 02:56:46', '2012-12-10 02:53:19']

Unfortunatly the script returns the lowest one, not the one closest to the time now.

Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: I will do it this way (use function filter): `print filter( lambda t: currentTimeMachine  < datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), examples )[0]`

Comment: You don't need `[x for x in foo]`; it's the same as `list(foo)`. Meanwhile, it's silly to create a list comprehension and then pass it to `filter` (especially when you need a `lambda` function to wrap the predicate) instead of just putting an `if` clause into the comprehension.